# Pdf viewer can't be updated with log file : pdfTeX entering extended mode

Tags: texmaker

I am sorry if this question sounds stupid in some ways. Here is my very first try. I installed Miktex followed by TexMaker for writing math equation.

I got Log file error

```
LOG FILE :
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (MiKTeX 2.9.6350 64-bit) (preloaded format=latex 2017.8.25) 25 AUG 2017 15:21
entering extended mode
```

for the code

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
f(W,H) &= D_{kl}(W,H) + \lambda \omega(H)\\
&\leq D^+_{kl}(W,H,\pi) + \lambda \omega(H, \gamma)\\
&\stackrel{def.}{=} U(W,H,\pi,\lambda,\gamma)\\
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

The Pdfviewer aside does not update itself when I clicked run arrow next to quick build but show the previous version that I can manage to save somehow. Now the save option cannot be clicked. The files that are created with this `.tex` including `.dvi`, `.aux`, `.pdf`, and `.log`. All configure is in default setting.

Comment: Don't use "quick build". Switch to pdflatex. If it still don't work: Use another editor.

Comment: the log file you show is not an error, that is the startup banner it will say that every time.